# Terraform not recognizing import block when creating SQL Server database

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am attempting to create a database using terraform in Azure from a bacpac located in a storage account. According to [this documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/mssql_database#create_mode) it should be doable using the azurerm_mssql_database import block however it throws an error when attempting this.

This is the relevant section of my tf code:

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "database" {
  name           = var.database_name
  server_id      = azurerm_mssql_server.sql_server.id
  collation      = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
  license_type   = "LicenseIncluded"
  max_size_gb    = 4
  sku_name       = "Basic"
  import {
    storage_uri                  = var.bacpac_url
    storage_key                  = var.access_key
    storage_key_type             = "StorageAccessKey"
    administrator_login          = var.sql_user
    administrator_login_password = var.sql_password
    authentication_type          = "Sql"
  }
```

However running this returns the following error:

> Error: Unsupported block type
>
> on main.tf line 187, in resource "azurerm_mssql_database"
> "database":
> 187:   import {
> Blocks of type "import" are not expected here.

I think it clearly confusing the import block with an import for bringing existing resources under terraform management. Is there an error in my syntax that is causing this or is there a new approach I should be using? I am using terraform version 1.5.2 and version 3.0.2 of the azurerm provider if that helps.

I have tried using create_mode [however that seems to be broken as well](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/20149)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `import` block was [enabled](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/18588) in version 3.27.0 of the AzureRM provider. You would need to update the provider to a minimum of that version, such as with the semantic versioning below:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.27.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Man, you saved my bacon there, I have been banging my head on this for hours. I think I copied that version from the documentation and didn't even think to check if it was the newest version.

Answer (score 2):

Support for import block for database has been added in azurerm provider version 3.27.0 and above.

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/18588
[image]

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/releases/tag/v3.27.0

Below works (assuming using latest or version 3.27.0 of azurerm provider).

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "example" {
  name                         = "example-sqlserver"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "4dm1n157r470r"
  administrator_login_password = "4-v3ry-53cr37-p455w0rd"
}


resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "database" {
  name           = "example-database-qwerty"
  server_id      = azurerm_mssql_server.example.id
  collation      = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
  license_type   = "LicenseIncluded"
  max_size_gb    = 4
  sku_name       = "Basic"
  import {
    storage_uri                  = var.bacpac_url
    storage_key                  = var.access_key
    storage_key_type             = "StorageAccessKey"
    administrator_login          = var.sql_user
    administrator_login_password = var.sql_password
    authentication_type          = "Sql"
  }
}
variable "bacpac_url" {
  type = string
}
variable "access_key" {
  type = string
}
variable "sql_user" {
  type = string
}
variable "sql_password" {
  type = string
}
```